# Detecting Last Window/Tab Close with ActionCable

Tags: ruby-on-rails, actioncable

I'm trying to find a way to detect that the last window or tab for a user is being closed so I can can do some cleanup; but I can't seem to find a way to detect that it is in fact the last connection for the user.   I have a model that tracks connections to my channels, and I don't want to remove a user's connection record when they disconnect if they have other active tabs open with connections.

So I need someway to check each disconnect to see if their are other active connections with the same identifier.

I've tried setting up a check on the RemoteConnections in the disconnect method.  But when that gets called it seems like the connection that's closing is still returned under the RemoteConnections.

```
module ApplicationCable
  class Connection < ActionCable::Connection::Base
    identified_by :current_user

    def connect
      self.current_user = find_verified_user
      logger.add_tags 'ActionCable', current_user.username
      logger.debug self.current_user.username + " now connected."
    end

    def disconnect
      self.close()
      logger.debug ActionCable.server.remote_connections.where(current_user: current_user)
      logger.debug ActionCable.server.remote_connections.where(current_user: current_user).identifiers
      logger.debug ActionCable.server.remote_connections.where(current_user: current_user).identifiers.inspect()
    end
end
```

This setup returns the following, even when the last connection using that identifier is closing:

```
[ActionCable] [swachtma@gmail.com] UserChannel stopped streaming from user:Z2lkOi8vYWxseWNoYXQvVXNlci80Nw
[ActionCable] [swachtma@gmail.com] #<ActionCable::RemoteConnections::RemoteConnection:0x00000007062690>
[ActionCable] [swachtma@gmail.com] #<Set:0x00000007791b78>
[ActionCable] [swachtma@gmail.com] #<Set: {:current_user}>
```

I've been addressing this so far by setting up a model just to track connections as they open and close for each channel.  But it adds a lot of overhead, and it's a mess to manage.

Can anyone suggest a way to manage this?  I've been scouring the API documentation for ActionCable and coming up empty.

Answer (score 1):

I found a solution for this that might not work for everyone, but since these are several SO questions open for this with no answer, I thought I'd post what I ended up with and maybe it will help someone else.

I abandoned the idea of querying the cable server to count active connections.  If this is currently possible, I am apparently not wise enough to find the answer.

I also experimented with using Active Record to count active connections, store GIDS to identify them, and do cleanup when the last connection closed.  It worked... but I am not a fan, as it added a ton of extra queries, a new model to track subscriptions, and a lot of sensitivity around timing of cleanup work.  Possible, but ugly.

Instead I adopted a concept of "master" and "slave", connections, as well as an additional UserChannel (driven by my user authentication).  Basically the connection that initiates the first subscription become the "master" connection (to a chat room, in my case).  When the master joins I broadcast a notice to all other active windows/tabs authenticated as the same user over the UserChannel.  Those that receive this broadcast, follow the master connection by setting up connections on a separate, but paired slave channel.  The "master" connection, also sets up a matching "slave" connection of its own.

So for each chatroom I maintain 2 channels: room_#*slave, and room*#_master

All broadcasts for the chatrooms activity happen on the "slave" channel (since it is available to all sessions for the user, whereas only one window/tab is subscribed to the master).  New messages, user exits, entrances, etc. get broadcast here.

The "master" channel, only exists to handle setup and teardown.  When the user joins, the master channel's "subscribed" method broadcasts the entry of that user to other users through the "slave" channel.

When the master connection is closed, it's "unsubscribed" method broadcasts the exit, handles the active record cleanup, and broadcasts a message to all slave connections for that user to enter a suspended state.  The slaves can then opt in (with user action) to become the new master connection, in which case the connection is restored.

This was the best balance I could find; only one window/tab counts for the connection as far as ActiveRecord is concerned.  If that window is closed, the user has "left".  However, the slave channel lets me keep a common state across all a user's browser windows/tabs as they still witness all the broadcast sent.  If the user closes the "master" connection accidentally, they have an easy path to rejoin.